# How do I set a core-animated-pages-transition-end event handler?

Tags: polymer

Tried something like this but does not work?

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="select">
 <template>
     <core-animated-pages fit selected="{{select}}" id="core_page">
             ....
     </core-animated-pages>
 </template>    
 <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        select:0,
        ready: function(){
            this.$.core_page.addEventListener("core-animated-pages-transition-end", function(e) {
                console.log('Hello')
             })
        }
    });
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me out of the box: http://jsbin.com/wekux/1/edit

By the way, it's easier to use declarative event handlers (install of using addEventListener):

```
<core-animated-pages fit .. on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{transitionEnd}}">
```

Comment: It clearly works in your example jsbin, but for me it doesn't work in a polymer template both declarative or manually. It must be something stupid I am doing wrong here...

Comment: Aaaa I knew it was something stupid, I am not using a transition lol except from the slide right from the parent element... ok going to try something...

Comment: My brains can't handle it, element2 changes page on element1 but it has to wait for the parent animation to finish? `<parent><elm1/><elm2/></parent>`

Comment: Found a way to do it on the parent `transitionEnd: function(e){this.page=this.getPage;},`